# Need a visa to travel to India as former OCI?

Tags: visas, india

My partner (Australian citizen) had an OCI card, but hasn't renewed it yet (she has a new passport). However, we need to go to India for family reasons very soon, and the OCI renewal process appears to be quite lengthy.

- Can she still travel to India with her OCI, even though she hasn't renewed it since she changed passport?

**or**

- Is it possible for her to apply for and travel with a tourist visa, even though she has an OCI?

Thanks!